# Make imported python program run from its position in the file system

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, python-import

I want to have a control program where I initialize other python programs from but these programs should refer to their own folder.

If I import them from the control program, it will refer to the folder of the control program and not the sub program.

c:/python3.5/control.py

c:/my documents/data/program1.py

c:/my documents/datab/program2.py

```
#control program
input('good day general, what planet would you like to destroy today?')
if 1:
    import '...program1.py'
if 2:
    import program2.py
```

_

```
#program1.py
file = open('textfile.txt','a')
file.write(xxx)
```

It will write the textfile into c:/python3.5 instead of c:/my documents/data1

How do I make it write to the sub programs folder without writing the whole thing (c:my documents...)? I would like to make it possible to put the sub programs anywhere and write to a file in that directory.

Strangely enough, I had a similiar setup a couple of years back and then I could import and have it write automatically to the sub program folder.

Comment: `__file__` is the actual (full) path of the file/module it is used in. `os.path.abspath(__file__)` will thus give you the full path to that module.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the directory of where a file is you can:

```
import os
# If the directory is of a python module eg program2.py
dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
# If you know the file path already
dirname2 = os.path.dirname("C:\\My Documents\\data1")
```